# Cant include "\\" in a string JS/Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I use atom editor... and I am trying to create a snippet for it. Not sure if that info matters or not. But the snippet file is written in coffeescript (snippets.cson is file name).

Anyways.. I cant seem to get a backslash to appear in a string.. I know that escaping it with a backslash(like this: \\) should do the trick.. but it is not working.

Here is the full string I'm working with:

"print('\\33[f\\33[2J')"

Shouldn't that print as this(?):

"print('\33[f\33[2J')"

```
'.source.python':
   'Clear Screen':
     prefix: 'clear'
     body: """
            print('\\33[f\\33[2J')
            """
```

Comment: It does — https://jsfiddle.net/4tx8cvv8/ — you need to provide a real [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin Had to hit the hay. Didnt realize it was already 5 a.m. I have a dentist appointment at 1. ... I'll copy and paste the full snippet after I get home from that.

Comment: @Quentin Hello, I added the snippet code in the original post.

Comment: @Spock you could add what is currently being printed; when I run `console.log("print('\\33[f\\33[2J')")` in dev tools, it is working as expected.